# Long gcc compile time

Tags: compiling, make, gcc

So far my compilations have either succeeded or failed but his time it just got stuck. I'm compiling gcc on a Linux Synology NAS. However, the compilation process has run for 3 days and I start to think that it will never finish. From ps I get the following output:

```
27513 root      2536 S    /opt/bin/bash -c r=`${PWDCMD-pwd}`; export r; \ s=`cd .; ${PWDCMD-pwd}`; export s; \ if test -f stage1-lean  ; then \   echo Skipping rebuild of
27866 root      2468 S    /opt/bin/bash -c build/genautomata ../.././gcc/config/rs6000/rs6000.md \   insn-conditions.md > tmp-automata.c
27867 root      432m D    build/genautomata ../.././gcc/config/rs6000/rs6000.md insn-conditions.md
31539 root      2924 S    grep build
```

The last write to tmp-automata.c was 2.5 days ago. The NAS has only 64 MB RAM so I expected long compile time but not at this level. The average CPU load for the build process is 5-10%. What could be wrong? How do I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like the compile needs about 500 megs of memory, and since the system only has 64 megs, the system is thrashing: It is using swap, which works but is really, really slow.

Is there a reason you are compiling this on a system with so little memory?  If it's an embedded system with a custom CPU, I would cross-compile on another system.

Comment: I'm trying to add Tellstick support but the compiler version available via the ipkg package system is 3.3.4, which is too old to work. I guess I have to try cross-compiling instead of native compiling.